# Issues looping through an array

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, foreach

So, I'm using a database to store ship data.

As I load data into the database, I am checking whether the ship already exists. Sometimes, more than one ship has the same name. This code tries to go through the array, pull out all the ships with the same name, and then ask, in turn if that is the right one- if not, then it's yet another with the same name.

```
 $sql = "SELECT Ship_Primary_Key, ship_original_rate, Ship_Launch_Year from Ships WHERE Ship_Name = '" . $shipname . "'";
 $result = $conn->query ($sql);
 if ($result-> num_rows > 0) //Does the ship name already exist in the DB? {
     $ships_in_db = mysqli_fetch_all ($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
     foreach ($ships_in_db as $row) {
         echo "new record is " . $shipname . " as a " . $shiprate . ". Records already include " . $shipname . ", launched " . $row["Ship_Launch_Year"] . " as a " .  $row ['ship_original_ra
         $yesno = trim(fread(STDIN,5));
         if ($yesno == "y" || $yesno == "yes") {
             //ship already exists in the DB. Get the Key
             echo $shipname . " is not new to the database and the key is " . $row["Ship_Primary_Key"]  . "\n";
             $shipkey = $row["Ship_Primary_Key"];
             break 1;
          }
      }

      //if you get through the loop of ships without assigning a primary key, ship is new
      if (empty($shipkey)) {
          $shipkey = write_ship_to_DB($shipname,$shiprate,$launchyear,$launchname,$conn);
      }
  }
```

So the problem is, I know that I have at least *three* ships with the same name in the first set of data (that are different). The problem is, it only ever asks about the first one. When I put 'n', it just goes on, and never asks about the *second* ship with the same name that already exists.

I think it's a problem with the Foreach loop and the break statement.
I'd appreciate any help with this

Comment: Did you tried to do `var_dump($ships_in_db)` to see what's in the array?

Comment: what happen if you tried to remove the break? the break obviously stops the loop statement after it passes with your condition on your `yesno` variable, I can't seem to understand what your condition is doing.

Comment: Something seems to have changed actually- for some reason, only *one* ship with the same name is returned.. I need to investigate this.

Comment: I've simplified the code into a [simpler form](https://codeshare.io/GqNoQj). And it works as expected. Could you please try this on your computer and see what happens?

Comment: I'm sorry, where's your simplified code?

Comment: The page the "simpler form" text links to.

Comment: You were ride- this code (my version or your simplified version) works fine. It was me forgetting to reset a variable at the beginning of each loop that got me.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem.

Because of the loop- I wasn't resetting the "Ship_Id" variable, which meant that the second or nth time a ship with the same name came around, a new ship wasn't created.

Now I've solved that. So the problem isn't this code at all- it's other code.